# Pasar user id de blade a data vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Soy nuevo con vuejs, intento pasar un user_id de la vista de blade Laravel a la data de vue js, estuve todo el día investigando y no logro cumplir el objetivo. Me gustaría que me puedan brindar una ayuda.

El proceso es un usuario que se registra en un form y debe pasar a la pantalla de perfil para terminar de completar los datos, por eso necesito el user_id.

Mi código:

Controlador Inicial:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // Usuario::create($request->all());
        $usuario = new Usuario();
        $usuario->IdInstagram = $request->IdInstagram; 
        $usuario->contraseña = $request->contraseña;
        $usuario->save();

        return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'usuarioId' => $usuario->id), 200);
    }
```

En la vista blade:

```
<input type="hidden" :usuario_id="{{ $usuario->id }}" v-model="usuario_id">
```

Acá probé diversas variantes, v-bing, @json($usuario), :data etc.

La data:

```
data:{
        usuario_id: {}
    },
```

Acá también probé en cambiar el tipo de dato en vez de {}, '', [] etc.

El id lo paso desde vue en el primer método:

```
window.location.href = '/perfil/' + response.data.usuarioId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es sencillo has lo siguiente:

1. El data de Vue

```
    data:{
        usuario_id: ''
    },
```

2. En el archivo blade lo siguiente:

```
   <input type="text" :value="usuario_id='{{$usuario->id}}'" hidden>
```

3. Finalizando simplemente necesitas llamarlo en tu archivo vue con un

```
    $this->usuario_id
```

Comment: Funcionó justa había encontrado otra manera. Pero esta me gusta mucho más. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas template puedes usar un objeto llamado props

```
props: {
    usuario_id: Number,
}
```

en el blade, al llamar al template usalo de esta forma

```
<custom_template :usuario_id="{{ $usuario->id }}"></custom_template>
```

o bien, como lo tenias, solo corrigiendo el dato por :value

```
<input type="hidden" :value="{{ $usuario->id }}" v-model="usuario_id">
```

En ambos casos, puedes llamarlo por `$this->usuario_id`

Comment: Agradezco tu dedicación. No estoy muy familiarizado aun con los templates ya probé varias formas y me da error. Y agregando <input type="hidden" :value="{{ $usuario->id }}" v-model="usuario_id"> me indica el siguiente error: conflicts with v-model on the same element because the latter already expands to a value binding internally

Comment: Declara al inicio de data un valor por default, puede ser 0, pero tienes un object {}

Comment: Disculpá, pero me sale el mismo error. Si veo que en el error me muestra el id, por lo que entiendo que es una aproximación. No hay otra funcionalidad en vue que no sea v-model?